# Set the start of the time interval

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is there a way to set the starting time for a 4H interval?  When using a step chart, it seems like the crypto (BTCUSD) and and US equity (AMD) have a different starting and ending times for the step charts.  Can I set this in script?

Comment: You want the chart to display time in a specific 'time zone'?

Comment: No, not "time zones."  Just want to sync the start of different instruments.  all should start at 00:00 utc.  Right now they dont seem to be in sync. You can check using step line chart  of any moving average.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the issue isn't the time that markets are open? For a stock- like AMD- the chart time will appear as if it's wrong if the market is closed (between 4pm and 9:30am EST or UTC-5), but when its open the time should line up perfectly with BTC.

Comment: create a simple SMA on any chart, set in timeframe to 2 hours, change the style to step line.  the time breaks dont line up, For stock use extended hours.